# SQL code that will group the similar products under the main product

Tags: mysql, sql-server

So i have a database with a lot of chemical substances in it. 
i have main chemical substances here

http://postimg.org/image/p1xviagk7/

and here i have all other chemical substances that have slightly different names but they are the same. 
http://postimg.org/image/dyh76t08h/

there are a lot of Chemical substances with NULL ingredient_id

For example:
Camelia is the main chemical name. And ideally i want to write a code in sql that if sees

ORGANIC CAMELIA SINENSIS (WHITE TEA) LEAF EXTRACT

or

CAMELIA SINENSIS (WHITE TEA) LEAF EXTRACT

will group them under the main ingredient which is Camelia.

The way it works right now is that if i see the substance with NULL ingredient_id, i just search the similar name of it in the main chemical names folder or other substances and then if i find it i copy the id from the found substance and paste into the NULL ingredient_id.
I have like 30 thousands of NULL ingredient_id substances.

Is there some code that will match substances with NULL ingredient_id with other substances with similar names and then it will somehow copy their ingredient id. Or it could search under the main chemical names folder for the similar names, and if found will take this id.

I've done some research, and i've found that using Jaccard index i can solve this problem.

But i'm afirst year student at my first co-op and don't know how to implement it yet. 
If you need more information or you want me to clarify something, just tell me.

Just an update

So now i just need some code that will find all similar products with similar names and make their ID equal. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can try use mysql natural language search [link] (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-language-search.aspx) for searching products with similar names and get ingredient_id for product with best match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a join with wildcards:

```
create table #substances (s_name nvarchar(100));
create table #main_ingredients (mi_name nvarchar(100));
insert into #substances (s_name) values ('ORGANIC CAMELIA SINENSIS (WHITE TEA) LEAF EXTRACT'),('CAMELIA SINENSIS (WHITE TEA) LEAF EXTRACT'),('HIGH FRUCTOSE CORN SYRUP'),('WHEATFLOUR');
insert into #main_ingredients (mi_name) values ('Camelia'),('Fructose'), ('Wheat');

select  mi_name,
        s_name
from #substances as S
join #main_ingredients as M on
S.s_name like '%'+mi_name+'%';

drop table #substances;
drop table #main_ingredients;
```